# Timezone aware datetime field in Mysql with Django Rest Framework

Tags: mysql, django, datetime, django-rest-framework

I'm storing datetimes in Django in UTC format in a mysql db. I'm aware that mysql doesn't store datetimes with a timezone and the solution for most people seems to be to let the frontend convert the datetime to the client's current timezone.

That solution doesn't work for me as I need to know the timezone of the datetime on the server as I run cronjobs based on the datetimes and they need to be timezone aware.

The easiest solution seems to be to store the timezone in a separate db field and then do the conversion when I run the cronjob. I'm having a hard time believing that there's not a better way in 2018. Any ideas?